# Zebra printer 1D & 2D barcode generation & printing using python

Tags: python-2.7, barcode, python-module, zebra-printers, barcode-printing

I have Zebra USB printer,In which would like to generate Numeric-only barcodes,Alpha-numeric barcodes,2-Dimensional barcodes using python language.

- Is there any module to generate all types of Barcodes for given Data
- How to print That generated Barcode Directly using commands or generate Barocde lable as Image and then print.

I got some Modules with which I am able generate only some of the formats as image and able print that label.

so,Request you to please guide OR share the best methods to Geanrate & Print the Barcodes.

Comment: You can generate a label with Zebra Designer and print it into file. You will get a file which contains ZPL-Code. This code you can send directly to the printer, when you replaced your variables.